# Why doesn't requirements.txt work in an Alexa-hosted (Python) environment?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I noticed that requirements.txt doesn't work.

For example, create a new skill (select Alexa-hosted (Python)).
Next, as an example, edit requirements.txt and add `openai` as shown below.
`boto3` and `ask-sdk-core` are listed by default.

```
boto3==1.28.78
ask-sdk-core==1.19.0
openai
```

Next, modify lambda_function.py and add `import openai` to the beginning.
When I deploy and test the skill, it fail.

I check CloudWatch Logs, I see the following error:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'openai' Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Looking at the logs, it appears that openai is not installed.
However, when I read the [document](https://developer.amazon.com/en-AU/docs/alexa/hosted-skills/alexa-hosted-skills-create.html#dependencies), it says that I can write it in requirements.txt.

Could you please tell me how I can install additional libraries using requirements.txt?

The same problem occurred not only with `openai` but also with other libraries such as `firebase_admin`.

Specifying the version like `openai==1.7.1` did not solve the problem.

Retrying the deployment or recreating the skill did not resolve the problem.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue - wondering if it's something happening with AWS itself? I can't seem to find any deployment logs either - to confirm if the requirements.txt are actually being installed.
Have you looked into adding the dependency directly on to the code base?

Comment: This is really more of a Lambda question so you might want to tag it for that. You're better off adding your modules to a .zip or using Layers. Have a look at this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#deployment-pkg-for-virtualenv

Comment: @foobrew Yes, I would consider including dependencies directly in the code. However, for the Alexa-hosted environment, all I need to do is edit requirements.txt and deploy, so I hope this will be fixed.

Comment: @CheekuJee There seems to be a problem with the Alexa-hosted environment. It seems like it is using CodeBuild, but I can't see the logs so I don't know anything... Although the article is in Japanese, it seems to have been working fine until at least July 2023.
https://qiita.com/saeki4n/items/599e5af2a280325c3225#%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%A0%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AD%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E6%A7%8B%E7%AF%89%E6%89%8B%E9%A0%86

Yes, I would also consider including direct dependency packages in my code. –

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the ASK CLI to deploy the code including the `openai` package and resolved it.

Please note that although you can deploy ZIP files from the console, you can only upload up to 100 files, making it impractical to deploy packages containing hundreds or thousands of files.

If you use an Alexa-Hosted environment and want to use an external library, the ASK CLI is probably the easiest way to do it.

The easiest way is to just write it in requirements.txt like the official documentation and deploy it, but I would like to see this feature fixed.

Comment: Do you mean that merely using the CLI "ask deploy" causes the requirements.txt to be handled properly?